# TMXLoader in AndEngine

Tags: android, png, andengine

I'm using png format for tiling and using TMXLoader to load my tiled map. The problem occured when my code running in android device not in the emulator. Somehow, any image that use png for backend (map) is displayed grayly in the device. However, my tmxLoader seems to be fine loading the tiled map, no throwing exception at all. I'll give the screenshot in device and emulator. Is this the problem in android (maybe libpng ??).

[image: emulator image]
[image: device image]

Comment: It's one of my game development subject task in earlier semester. It's an adventure game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it's solved. It's because the png format that i created (maybe because of some options when saving the png) cannot be read by tmx loader engine, because later on, i tried to save it without using any options at all, it loaded nicely in the device (solved)